# What is the best way to store images in a numpy array for building a CNN with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-science

imaging you have 30000 images with 20x20 pixels.

How would you store them into a NumPy array regarding mathematical operations like standardization and simplicity of feeding them into a CNN which should build with tensorflow.keras?

I have seen a lot of store techniques from a 2D up to a 4D. I am kinda confused about it.

many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would store them in an array of shape `(30000, 20, 20)`, which is the industry standard. If this confuses you you can see this as simply a list of images. The first 'dimension' just selects which image it is. Perhaps this image helps understanding:

[image]